# How to customize the tooltip in d3plus.full.js for rings?

Tags: javascript, d3plus

I'm trying the d3plus charts in a project where I need to customize the tooltip which appears on right top corner for rings. This [D3PLUS Example](http://d3plus.org/examples/advanced/10503491/)

I have connection with an extra field as follows

`var connections = [ { "source": "alpha", "target": "beta", "strength": 200, "grade":"A" },
    { "source": "alpha", "target": "gamma", "strength": 10, "grade": "A" },
    { "source": "beta", "target": "delta", "strength": 5, "grade": "B" },
    { "source": "beta", "target": "epsilon", "strength": 1.563, "grade": "B" },
    { "source": "zeta", "target": "gamma", "strength": 3.125, "grade": "A" },
    { "source": "theta", "target": "gamma", "strength": 0.732, "grade": "A" },
    { "source": "eta", "target": "gamma", "strength": 2.063, "grade": "B" }  ]`

I want to list the `grade` as a bullet point under each source.

I tried a lot by reverse engineering the d3plus.full.js but no success. Is it possible by any means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it by `jquery`. On `document` ready `select` the `.class` and add element. The example below is on click of a button like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn").on('click',function(){
        console.log("Hello");
        $(".d3plus_tooltip_focus_link").each(function (indx) {
            console.log(indx + " : " + $(this).text());
        });         
    });
});
```